# What is this object instantiation syntax called? Object obj = new();

Tags: c#

Microsoft documentation has a code example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file#append-text-to-an-existing-file) that uses syntax for instantiating an object that I have not seen before. I searched the web for more information on this syntax as well as I could, but I could not seem to find additional information. The object is instantiated with the new keyword, but no class name. I assume the type is inferred from the variable it is being assigned to, but I would like to know more, specific information about this operation.

Does this instantiation syntax have a specific name? Does anyone have a link to some official documentation that explains which versions of the language support this feature, or any additional information?

```
 using StreamWriter file = new("WriteLines2.txt", append: true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Target typed new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) (introduced in C# 9)

Comment: Thank you. I found the answer just after posting the question by changing the constructor in my IDE to what I would normally expect. Then, I noticed that if I hovered over it there was a code style suggestion IDE0090 to simplify the expression. That lead me to the answer. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer.